# "DisallowedHost" problem on docker container with digitalocean

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a dockerized website built with django and react. I have created a docker container with nginx and gunicorn for django. Everything works fine on local, but when i deploy on the server i get this error
[image]

Why is this happening ? also, it seems to be taking the settings from... i don't know, a default settings.py? i.e. My ALLOWED_HOSTS configuration, is not the same as this

[image: settings.py on traceback]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not correctly defined for your application. Have you changed your settings path?

If that's not the case, check your DigitalOcean's DNS. The A records should match your droplet assigned IP.

Comment: It was. The DNS record was pointing to an old droplet. Just checked the droplet ip and replaced. It works. Thanks!